# <Electron> session.will-download event fired over one time

Tags: javascript, electron

## I am using electron with `session.will-download` event,  and has encountered a problem.

I embed a web in `<webview>`, and inside the web has a download link will download the pdf file, I am trying to download the pdf with a specific directory, it will trigger the `will-download`. that's perfect, but as I click more times, I found actually it triggers not only one time.

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 1100, height: 680 })
    mainWindow.loadURL(isDev ? 'http://localhost:3000' : `file://${path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html')}`)
    mainWindow.on('closed', () => (mainWindow = null))

    mainWindow.webContents.on('did-attach-webview', (event, webContents) => {
        console.log('did-attach-webview emmit')
        webContents.on('new-window', (event, url) => {
            console.log(' ------ new-window .. -----')
            event.preventDefault()

            const win = new BrowserWindow({ show: false })
            win.once('ready-to-show', () => win.show())
            win.loadURL(url)
            event.newGuest = win

            const session = win.webContents.session
            session.on('will-download', (event, item, webContents) => {
                console.log(`${url} will-download ...`)
                const saveFileName = item.getFilename()
                item.setSavePath(`/Users/yang/Desktop/electron_practice/electron-react/src/${saveFileName}`)
            })
        })
    })
```

And below is the log I print

```
[1]  ------ new-window .. -----
[1] Blocked http://alp-rfb6-hjap01.alp.com.tw:30000/core/Default.html from calling focus on its opener.
[1] http://alp-rfb6-hjdb01/ReportServer?%2fB6_Waybill_C&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF&wh_id=RF-B6-2&order_number=DY01190503024 will-download ...
[1]  ------ new-window .. -----
[1] Blocked http://alp-rfb6-hjap01.alp.com.tw:30000/core/Default.html from calling focus on its opener.
[1] http://alp-rfb6-hjdb01/ReportServer?%2fB6_Waybill_C&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF&wh_id=RF-B6-2&order_number=DY01190503024 will-download ...
[1] http://alp-rfb6-hjdb01/ReportServer?%2fB6_Waybill_C&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF&wh_id=RF-B6-2&order_number=DY01190503024 will-download ...
[1]  ------ new-window .. -----
[1] Blocked http://alp-rfb6-hjap01.alp.com.tw:30000/core/Default.html from calling focus on its opener.
[1] http://alp-rfb6-hjdb01/ReportServer?%2fB6_Waybill_C&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF&wh_id=RF-B6-2&order_number=DY01190503024 will-download ...
[1] http://alp-rfb6-hjdb01/ReportServer?%2fB6_Waybill_C&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF&wh_id=RF-B6-2&order_number=DY01190503024 will-download ...
[1] http://alp-rfb6-hjdb01/ReportServer?%2fB6_Waybill_C&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF&wh_id=RF-B6-2&order_number=DY01190503024 will-download ...
[1]  ------ new-window .. -----
[1] Blocked http://alp-rfb6-hjap01.alp.com.tw:30000/core/Default.html from calling focus on its opener.
[1] http://alp-rfb6-hjdb01/ReportServer?%2fB6_Waybill_C&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF&wh_id=RF-B6-2&order_number=DY01190503024 will-download ...
[1] http://alp-rfb6-hjdb01/ReportServer?%2fB6_Waybill_C&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF&wh_id=RF-B6-2&order_number=DY01190503024 will-download ...
[1] http://alp-rfb6-hjdb01/ReportServer?%2fB6_Waybill_C&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF&wh_id=RF-B6-2&order_number=DY01190503024 will-download ...
[1] http://alp-rfb6-hjdb01/ReportServer?%2fB6_Waybill_C&rs:Command=Render&rs:Format=PDF&wh_id=RF-B6-2&order_number=DY01190503024 will-download ...
```

I guess it's the problem occurs on the session, it should be closed after the download is done, or something else.
Are there anyone meets the problem also :(

Answer (score 1):

try closing the window once the download is completed, issue with multiple session will-download handlers gets registered. closing the window after download can help I think. Please try and let me know.

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 1100, height: 680 })
    mainWindow.loadURL(isDev ? 'http://localhost:3000' : `file://${path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html')}`)
    mainWindow.on('closed', () => (mainWindow = null))

    mainWindow.webContents.on('did-attach-webview', (event, webContents) => {
        console.log('did-attach-webview emmit')
        webContents.on('new-window', (event, url) => {
            console.log(' ------ new-window .. -----')
            event.preventDefault()

            const win = new BrowserWindow({ show: false })
            win.once('ready-to-show', () => win.show())
            win.loadURL(url)
            event.newGuest = win

            const session = win.webContents.session
            session.on('will-download', (event, item, webContents) => {
                console.log(`${url} will-download ...`)
                const saveFileName = item.getFilename()
                item.setSavePath(`/Users/yang/Desktop/electron_practice/electron-react/src/${saveFileName}`)

            item.once('done', (event, state) => {
             if (state === 'completed') {
              win.close();
             } else {
              win.close();
             }
            })
            })
        })
    })
```